# How to use Hand Tracking to get landmarks with MediapipeUnityPlugins?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mediapipe

I asked ChatGPT for the code and it got error

> CS0079: The event 'PoseTrackingGraph.OnPoseLandmarksOutput' can only
> appear on the left hand side of += or -=

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Mediapipe.Unity.PoseTracking;
using Mediapipe;

public class LandmarkProcessor : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject poseTrackingPrefab;
private PoseTrackingGraph poseTrackingGraph;

    void Start()
    {
        poseTrackingGraph = poseTrackingPrefab.GetComponent<PoseTrackingGraph>();
        poseTrackingGraph.OnPoseLandmarksOutput.AddListener(OnPoseLandmarks);
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        // Process the latest pose landmarks here
    }
    
    void OnPoseLandmarks(NormalizedLandmarkList landmarkList)
    {
        Debug.Log(landmarkList);
        // Process the pose landmarks here
    }

}
```

I changed the a line of code to: `poseTrackingGraph.OnPoseLandmarksOutput += OnPoseLandmarks;`
It got error

> CS0123: No overload for 'OnPoseLandmarks' matches delegate
> 'EventHandler<OutputEventArgs<NormalizedLandmarkList>>'

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of your `OnPoseLandmarks()` function are not matching the ones required by the OnPoseLandmarksOutput event.
The correct call is:

```
poseTrackingGraph.OnPoseLandmarksOutput += OnPoseLandmarks;
```

The correct method to call is:

```
private void OnPoseLandmarks(object stream, OutputEventArgs<NormalizedLandmarkList> eventArgs)
{
   // DO YOUR THING
}
```